# Email template documentation?

Tags: magento2.2, email-templates

Is there documentation anywhere for the email template syntax, specifically the available |[filter] options available for formatting values for display in an email?

I see in some of the example emails that they use a syntax of `{{ var someVariable |raw }}` -- what I'm looking for are what the things are after the '|' that are available, how I might add more and/or what the syntax (and code location) of those might be.

Comment: check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

Answer (score 1):

The scripting language inside email template is called **Twig**. According to [Official Twig Documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#filters), the pipe symbol (|) inside delimiters(it means the `{{}}`) are "Filters". You can use it to modify the output.

[Here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/index.html) is the list that you can use for the filter.

Comment: ahhh , thanks. I was wondering if that was something like Twig or something proprietary. (I couldn't even find any documentation that said that!) Greatly appreciated!

Comment: ok, I've tried |number_format, |number_format(2), number_format(2,'.',','), |round(2) -- none of them do anything to the value displayed

Comment: I didn't have a try on it. Usually I handle value filter before outputting to email template.